# Javascript Regex - add only a character to matched string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to create a JS regex that matches a a string inside a given piece of code by it's beggining and ending and then only adds one character to that matched string.

Please see below what I mean:

**Imagine that I supply the following code:**

```
<div>
    <p>This is just some random text</p>
    <a href="https://somerandomsrc.com">
        <img src="https://somerandomsrc.com" alt="random image">
    </a>
    <img src="https://someotherrandomsrc.com" alt="another random image">
</div>
```

What I need to do is to have the script finding all instances of `<img>` and add a closing slash to the `<img>` elements so I would have something like this:

```
<div>
    <p>This is just some random text</p>
    <a href="https://somerandomsrc.com">
        <img src="https://somerandomsrc.com" alt="random image" />
    </a>
    <img src="https://someotherrandomsrc.com" alt="another random image" />
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
T

Comment: Why? HTML doesn't require that slash. Are you converting HTML to XML?

Comment: Actually, JSX. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually regex should be avoided for dealing with html/xml, but since your `img` tag seems broken and `img` tags are not nested, you can use following regex,

```
(<img[^>]*)>
```

and replace it with

```
$1 />
```

and fix your broken `img` tags.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3DMJDJ/1)

```js
const s = `<div>
    <p>This is just some random text</p>
    <a href="https://somerandomsrc.com">
        <img src="https://somerandomsrc.com" alt="random image">
    </a>
    <img src="https://someotherrandomsrc.com" alt="another random image">
    <img src="https://someotherrandomsrc.com" alt="another random image" />
</div>`

console.log('Before: ' + s);
console.log('After: ' + s.replace(/(<img[^>]*[^/])>/g,'$1 />'));
```

Edit1:

Yes just change the regex to `(<img[^>]*[^/])>` so that it won't match the one which already has a proper closing tag `/>`.

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3DMJDJ/2)

Comment: It works perfectly. Now I have another question. What If the given code has an image where the `<img>` element already has an ending slash? Using your solution gives me two ending slashes. Is there any way I can go around it so the code puts slashes in tags that don't have them and keeps just one slash where there is already one?

Comment: @Slaveworx: Yes we can change the regex slightly so already closed tags won't match giving you two slashes. Updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the `img` and its content in a group `(<img\s.*?)` except the closing tag and use `replace` with a global flag to replace after it with `/` slash.

```js
const string = `<div>
    <p>This is just some random text</p>
    <a href="https://somerandomsrc.com">
        <img src="https://somerandomsrc.com" alt="random image">
    </a>
    <img src="https://someotherrandomsrc.com" alt="another random image">
</div>`

const result = string.replace(/(<img\s.*?)>/g, '$1 />') 

console.log(result)
```